# I try to read gz file into R, but got an error message: line 1 did not have 9 elements

Tags: r

Here is my code:

```
imdb <- read.table(gzfile("/imdb_dataset/title.basics.tsv.gz"), sep = " ")
```

The error:

```
Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
  line 1 did not have 9 elements
```

The file, where you can see how the columns is separated etc.

[image: screenshot of tsv]

In fact, the first line has 9 elements, so what could be the issue?

```
tt0000010   short   Exiting the Factory La sortie de l'usine Lumière à Lyon 0   1895    \N  1   Documentary,Short
tt0000011   short   Akrobatisches Potpourri Akrobatisches Potpourri 0   1895    \N  1   Documentary,Short
tt0000012   short   The Arrival of a Train  L'arrivée d'un train à La Ciotat    0   1896    \N  1   Action,Documentary,Short
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 potential problems with your import:

1. You give a space (`" "`) instead of a tab (`"\t"`) as the delimiter but you say it's a tsv
2. There are a bunch of `\N` characters that could throw it off - try replacing those

Comment: There are 11 million \N in the file, and when qi

Comment: @use1883 Sorry, I think your comment was truncated? Did you try reading it in with `"\t"` as the delimiter (`sep`)? If you still have the problem please mention what OS you're on as it may affect what your options are. Also, just as a quick test, you may try `na.strings = c("\N" , "\\N" )` or some variation on that.

Comment: I tried to replace the \N ( with 0) both in text editor and in R, but I think the amount of "\N" is so large, that both these programs freeze and text editor just shuts down. I am using Mac. I did try to read it with "\t", but it didn't help the problem.

Comment: @use1883 I wouldn't recommend using a GUI app. Here's what I would do. First just write the first few lines of text into a new file to work with or only try to read in the first few lines from the same file, so that you can verify that we know what's causing the problem. Second, if the problem is the `\N` then we'll use a command line solution to replace it or the other possible solutions I mentioned. Did you try `na.strings`?

Comment: When I tried to read the first 10 rows everything was fine, but when I try to read the eleventh it puts out na error, that there are element mismatch and na.strings don't  help.

Comment: I also added the 10th, 11th and 12th line so you can see what could be the issue, but as far as I can tell, there are 9 elements on the 11th row.

Comment: @use1883 Can you include real data instead of a screenshot from the header to the problematic rows? That way we can work with it. Also, it could be the foreign accent mark on one of the letters - you can pick an appropriate encoding format that can handle that if that's not already done.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the data might be tab separated rather than space separated. Try `sep = "\t"` in the read.table. Also, probably want to add `header=T`